# What phone OS supports .net development?

Tags: c#, .net

As I know under Android applications developed in Java .
          under Apple Os applications developed in Objective C .

But under what Cellular OS main development language is c# with .net ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows phone 7 runs Silverlight and XNA which are both subsets of .NET, you can program them using C# or VB.

You can actually program iPhone, Android & Mac using the Mono tools from Novell: MonoDevelop, MonoTouch and MonoDroid (still beta)

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page
http://monodroid.net/
http://monotouch.net/
http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac

If you're wondering about production readiness - there are something like 30 mono apps that have made it into the iPhone top 500.

Comment: Regarding MonoTouch you do require a Mac and the SDK for iphone.

Comment: Yep pretty much, that's the advantage from Win/Anroid dev. Both can be done on windows :P

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 - It supports silverlight and XNA apps.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile 6 (CE), Windows Phone 7 - Compact Framework

iPhone OS - MonoTouch http://monotouch.net/

Android - MonoDroid http://monodroid.net/

Comment: I don't know about monotouch but MonoDroid is definitely not ready for anything close to serious development yet (more's the pity).